# I can't access array/obj outside jQuery event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, global

So I've got an object, or array, declared at the beginning of anything, outside everything:

```
var Thing = {title:'horse'};
```

Then I've got:-

```
$('.clickedIt').fadeOut(200, function() { console.log(Thing.title); }
```

That will fail. However, if I place above that same console log out of fadeOut, it'll be fine.

Comment: How does it fail? Where is the `fadeOut` called with respect to `Thing`?

Comment: can you provide a more complete script for us to look at? The problem here will laregely depend on the scope of `Thing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something to be global, just define it on the `window` Object.

```
window.Thing = { title: 'horse '};
```

Then use it like so:

```
$( '.clickedIt' ).fadeOut(200, function() { 
    console.log( window.Thing.title ); 
});
```

Just a note, putting a number of variables on the `window` Object is not recommended, I would recommend looking into name-spacing: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

Here is an example:

```
//simple JavaScript module
( function( window ) {
    //define your applications root namespace
    window.myApp = {
        Thing: { title: 'horse '}
    };
})( window );

//jQuery ready function
$( function() {
    $( '.clickedIt' ).fadeOut( 200, function() { 
        console.log( myApp.Thing.title ); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you assigned to title horse is undefined wrap it within quotes to make it string litral,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4VvKT/1/)**

```
var Thing = {title:'horse'};
$('.clickedIt').fadeOut(200, function() { console.log(Thing.title); })​
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP stated that it does work with the `console.log` put outside, so `horse` is not the issue.

Comment: It appeared as though you had just copy and paste the question. I see your alteration now you explain, but that was a typed demo, so it's not the issue.

Comment: I checked on fiddle it gave me error for horse undefined @pimvdb

Comment: Yes, you solved another question, understandably... hence the down vote was reversed. Thanks.

Comment: I solved this question check the accepted answer that also wrapped horse within quotes. I could not exactly understand what you mean?